# Serverless NodeJS File/Folder Structure

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm setting up my first project using [serverless](https://serverless.com) and while I'm finding a lot of great "getting started" tutorials, I'm having a hard time finding anything about actual project structure.

My thoughts is to use the below structure for my functions, shared libs and core configuration/dependencies:

```
.
├── functions/
│   │
│   ├── users/
│   │   ├── handler.js
│   │   └── serverless.yml
│   │
│   └── roles/
│       ├── handler.js
│       └── serverless.yml
│
├── shared/
│   └── common.js
│   
├── node_modules/
└── package.json
```

My main curiosity is around deployment and how that pertains to dependencies and shared files. Additionally, automating deploy of this structure seems strange as I'm gathering I would need to deploy each of the functions separately which I can script, but wondering if that's needed or advised.

Answer (score 4):

I have dealt with this a bit and found it quite frustrating. If you deploy from your setup, what does your api look like? With individual `serverless.yaml` files you end up with independent api endpoints (assuming you are triggering with api calls and not something like s3).

I ended up with a structure like this:

```
|- serverless/
|--- serverlsss.yml
|--- web pack.config.js
|--- dist/
|--- node_modules() /* dev and common code */
|--- src/
|----- function1/
|-------- node_modules
|-------- package.json
|-------- index.js
|----- function2/
|-------- node_modules
|-------- package.json
|-------- index.js
```

I use the serverless webpack plugin to output the the individual functions into the `dist/` directory. The `serverless.yaml` then points to these.

The `webpack.config.js` looks like this:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'function1': './src/function1/index.js', 
    'function2': './src/function2/index.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
  output:{
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      /* Babel is nice, but it's adding a some bulk and I don't need it
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        include: __dirname,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }, */
      { 
        test: /\.json$/,
        loaders: ['json']} 
    ],
  },
};

//  externals: [nodeExternals()],
//  nodeExternals seems to break aws-sdk when serving locally
//  aws-sdk should be in dev-dependencies of root folder
//  that way it's available in dev but doesn't get packaged.
//  It's available to the lambdas when deployed.
```

After that just make sure you set the individual flag in `serverless.yml`

```
package:
  individually: true
```

The webpack plugin is quite nice and does most of the heavy lifting. With this I can do a single deploy and all the functions end up as individual lambda functions all under one api endpoint. You also get the Webpack dev server so you can run `serverless webpack serve` to test your functions.

It was a bit of a pain to setup, but it's been working pretty well.

Comment: So you cannot change the timeout for individual function, thus resulting into timeout and no result given in response.

Comment: @Mark Meyer: would you mind help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58502648/how-to-add-a-custom-folder-and-file-via-yaml-in-serverless-app